# Масштабирование картинки не работает

Tags: joomla, html, php, css

Вопрос вот в чем, есть в слайдере картинка, она имеет max-width 100%, при изменении размера браузера в изначальной вёрстке она менялась как надо(уменьшалась). Как только поставил на joomla, всё пропало )))) точнее всё есть, а вот картинка масштабируется не сразу, а после обновления страницы, может кто знает как исправить?
мето тэг 
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/

Answer (score 1):

значит где то стандартный css перебивает ваш каким то тегом

Comment: нет не перебивает, я же написал, что после обновления она подгоняется под размер